# How to import multiproject build in buildSrc dir in Gradle?

Tags: plugins, gradle

Hi in my *buildSrc* dir I have two separate projects, lets name them **one** and **two**.
I add **build.gradle** and **settings.gradle** file in **buildSrc** dir and in them I wrote:
**settings.gradle**

```
include \
    "one",
    "two"
```

But when I tried to use some of the plugins, which are provided from this projects, Gradle says that this imports can not be found. I searched for simmilar problems and found that I have to write in **build.gradle** file in buildSrc:

```
dependencies {
    runtime subprojects.collect { owner.project(it.path) }
}
```

What does this line mean? And why I have to add it? **BuildSrc** adds copiled classes automatically on the *classpath*,or I am wrong?

Comment: Are You configuring project or build script itself? `buildSrc` is for script dependencies itself (not project's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle puts the "buildSrc project" and it's runtime dependencies on the buildscript classpath automatically but does not automatically put subprojects of buildSrc on your buildscript classpath.

If you have a multiproject build like described above, buildSrc is the root project but your custom logic is in the subprojects. Now when gradle puts buildSrc.jar on the buildscript classpath it is more or less empty.

The snippet

```
dependencies {
    runtime subprojects.collect { owner.project(it.path) }
}
```

adds all your subproject as runtime dependencies to your root buildSrc project. This should fix your problem as Gradle puts the buildSrc *AND* it's runtime dependencies on the buildscript classpath.

Comment: OK. Now I understand the whole picture, but can't understand in ditails the snippet. Iterrate over all subprojects and add their path to owner. What is the owner? What this object consists of?

Comment: here, `owner`is the owner of the closure, or in other words it's a reference to the context where the closure was created. In the snippet above the context is the `dependencies{}` block. Have a look at http://victorsavkin.com/post/4135607663/groovy-resolve-strategies for more details about groovys closure delegate/owner.